# Can I override a controls properties with a XAML and CS template to make another control?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am already doing things like this to make a new object called LineTemplate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BoxView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
             x:Class="Ja.Templates.LineTemplate" 
             HeightRequest="1" 
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource LineSeparatorColor}" Margin="0" 
/>

namespace Ja.Templates
{
    public partial class LineTemplate : BoxView
    {
        public LineTemplate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

But can I do something like this where I set the resource in the template XAML without having to code the setting of SetDynamicResource in C#

```
namespace Ja.Templates
{
    public class Label : Label
    {
        public Label()
        {
            SetDynamicResource(Label.FontColorProperty, "TextColor");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand your question can you be more specific?

Comment: Do you want to custom control in xamarin forms?If so you could refer to this link.https://www.mfractor.com/blogs/news/custom-controls-in-xamarin-forms,  If not , Could you give me more information.